# What is mean of 700,150 number?

Tags: arduino-uno

```
 if ((leftsensor >= 700) && (rightsensor >= 700))
   forward();
       else if((leftsensor <= 150) && (rightsensor <= 150))
   backward();
   else if((leftsensor <= 150) && (rightsensor >= 700))
   turnright();
   else if((leftsensor >= 700) && (rightsensor <= 150))
   turnleft();
```

Comment: The mean of 700 and 150 is 425. Or are you asking what they represent? They are some arbitrary threshold value that some sensor reading is being compared against.

Comment: A analogRead() value is between 0 and 1023. By looking at only that code we can only see that 700 and 150 are thresholds for steering a vehicle; a line-following robot?

Comment: As mentioned the mean of 700 and 150 is 425. What does this have to do with your code? Please be more clear about your scenario

Comment: those are you "shoulder" readings, while values between them are basically "dead space" (in joystick terms)

Answer (score 2):

I have somewhat large experience in understanding people that use "bad" english as their secondary language. That's why I assume that even though the question you asked was "**What is mean of 700,150 number?**" the question you wanted to ask is "**What is meaning of numbers 700,150 in code below?**"

This was already answered by @MaximilianGerhardt in the comments.

If we assume that `leftsensor`is an integer value coming from `analogRead` then it's possible values are between 0 and 1023. The programmed created two arbitrary thresholds of values 700 and 150. Those values were probably calculated experimentally to negate signal noise, sensor imperfections and interference.